# Webpage causing internet session being terminated in Android

Tags: android, jquery, responsive-design

I'm making a website from a template that I've downloaded. It's based on html5, jquery and is responsive. It works like a charm on ordinary computer, iPod, iPad and iPhone, but on Android tablet and smartphone I get the following problem:

Going to the startpage always works. When clicking a subpage, that page loads for a couple of seconds and then the whole internet session is aborted. All pages contain the same code all the way from DOCTYPE down to the maincontent and then the footer code also is the same on all pages, so howcome the startpage works but not the others? Going directly to another page than the startpage also causes this problem on Android.

I'm a newbie on this area and haven't got a clue what can be the problem, so unfortunately I don't know what more information I need to give to get any help.

Comment: How about posting your code, or at least the relevant parts of it? It's very difficult to determine what the problem could be otherwise ...

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is not a single solid thing. Actually, it's a list of features. Some browsers support them more than others. So this may be a case you got HTML5 feature not supported at your Android browser yet (this is why it produces unexpected behavior).

And as KenD requested, could you provide more details about the HTML5 code you have.